# Using text-overflow: ellipsis; on a parent div when the child is an input

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

I have multiple non-wrapping, inline child elements within a parent div that has a set `width` and `text-overflow` set to `ellipsis`.

When the last child is an anchor tag, the ellipses work fine, but when it's an input, the text just clips. Because the preceding items are variable width, I can't set a reasonable max width on the last input.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.parent {
    width: 120px;
    background: #eee;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1">
    <a href="#">link 1</a> text
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1">
    <a href="#">link 2</a> text
    <input type="submit" class="request-topic-link" value="lorem-ipsum-dolor">               
  </span>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5muarho3/).

Comment: A jsfiddle or equivalent would be helpful

Comment: `text-overflow`is designed to work on text, not input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is what I came up with. It needs some adjustments to your markup, but other than that it works.

a) The *submit input* can be safely replaced with a *button submit* that is also semantic and you can style it to your needs.
b) The simple text has to be wrapped within a `span`

Since you have variable content, the only way to do it is by using `table-cells` ...wrapped within a `table` obviously. Using `table-layout:fixed` would do the trick IF your content was not of variable width. This is why I added a width 33% to all table-cells which is just an indicator of what to be used; table-cells will disregard the set value and still expand accordingly and arbitrarily depending on their content.

Here is the updated markup and a working fiddle:
HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1">
    <a href="#">link 1</a> text <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>               </span>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span class="child1">
  <a href="#">link 1</a><span> textdfgg </span>
  <button type="submit" class="request-topic-link">lorem-ipsum-dolor</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child1 {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.child1 > * {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}

button {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5muarho3/3/